# What's the difference between Ubuntu GNOME and Ubuntu Unity with GNOME Shell installed from Ubuntu Software manager?

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm new to Ubuntu. Last night I installed GNOME Shell from the Ubuntu software manager. I really like this desktop environment. What the difference between doing this and installing Ubuntu GNOME? Would it be better if I downloaded Ubuntu GNOME instead of using the GNOME shell in place of Unity?

Also, if I get Ubuntu GNOME will the command lines used in terminal be different? I'm very new to Ubuntu so I don't want to start learning new command lines right now. For example, to install something it would still be `sudo apt-get install PackageName` correct?

Do different ubuntu flavours use different command lines in Terminal? Ubuntu different from Lubuntu different from Kubuntu, different from Ubuntu Gnome?

Comment: No, everything on the command line is pretty much the same. As to weather you install Gnome Shell from the software center or actually install Ubuntu Gnome, again not much difference. Ubuntu Gnome might give you some extra Gnome-specific software and applications (although you can also install these from the Software Centre), and it might also work more smoothly, with less things which don't work quite right. If Gnome Shell installed from Software Center works for you, by all means stick with. Yes, all the different Ubuntu flavors (Lubuntu, Kubuntu etc) are different.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll continue to use Gnome Shell since I haven't experienced any problems. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu GNOME comes with a different set of applications from Ubuntu with Unity, although some are the same. So that meas the only difference between installing regular Ubuntu first and then installing Gnome Shell, versus installing Ubuntu Gnome, is that you don't get the same applications. Although if you install the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package (I assume you installed `gnome-shell`), you will get the applications that come with Ubuntu Gnome.